# logrotate Uses All CPU Power

Tags: linux, debian, configuration, logrotate

I have default Debian 8.5 Jessie `/etc/logrotate.conf` contents:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

With this settings `logrotate` does its jobs well. However, if I change:

```
rotate 4
```

to something different, for example to:

```
rotate 5
```

`logrotate` never does its job, consuming all the CPU power so I have to kill its process eventually.

Why is that? Should I change something when tuning `rotate`?

Comment: actually I don't think my previous comments were right. I was confusing logrotate with rsyslog. Try looking for some command to parse/debug the logrotate config without actually applying it.

Comment: What is exactly the size of your log file?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have plenty of those.

Comment: any big log files?

Comment: No, everything is in range of  up to 1 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking for some command to parse/debug the logrotate config without actually applying it.

from `man logrotate`

> ```
>      -d, --debug                                                              
>             Turns  on  debug mode and implies -v.  In debug mode, no changes  
>             will be made to the logs or to the logrotate state file.
> ```

to use you would run

```
logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Comment: I've successfully debugged `logrotate`, some log files with really long log rotation times seemingly putted the tool into some kind of near-infinite loop. I've archived these logs manually and now `logrotate` runs just fine, even with `rotate 28` in `/etc/logrotate.conf`.

Comment: Used this to find that logrotate was "hanging" while reading the file /etc/logrotate.d/samba file.  Examining the /var/log/samba/ directory revealed thousands of (old) files with names indicating that they had been zipped and rotated numerous times.  So I binned them all.  Now to figure out how the mess came to be...  Running on xubuntu 20.04.

Comment: in my case, /var/log/samba got all messed up because there were two config fragments in /etc/logrotate.d  that affected logs in that directory. One named /etc/logrotate.d/winbind, and one named /etc/logrotate.d/samba. The first dealt solely with the log.winbindd file (winbindd process needs a HUP to switch to the new log), and the other with all the files in the samba directory. Given that samba itself manages log files, I removed the file /etc/logrotate.d/samba